# Software and/or developer library that can simulate multiple mouse devices?

Tags: software-development, simulation, mouse

I am looking for an library and/or software recommendation for simulation of more then one virtual mouse device. Ideally, the software will be able to create at least 4 or more mouse devices and send input to them (i.e. independent mouse movement, left click, right click, etc.). I would prefer it include a dll library for dot net software developers but it does not have to.

Basic Requirements:

1. Supports English
2. Windows 7 SP1
3. Sends mouse input such as independent mouse movement, left click, right click, and so on.
4. Needs to allow command line input so each mouse could be controlled independently or a library that allows simulation.

Optional but preferred requirements:

1. Has a dll library included with it that has at minimum dot net framework 4.0 support.

One possible library I found that was close was Microsoft's DSF(Device simulation framework) but documentation is poor at best on it.

What it is to be used for:
I plan on performing multi-mouse simulation in my software I am developing in dot net but cannot find a simulator.

More information:
The simulation is to simulate multiple players from a Kinect as independent mouse devices. A similar product that is not for the Kinect would be XPadder but it only supports one mouse. My coding attempt is here with DSF:

http://kinectmultipoint.codeplex.com.

Comment: Welcome to  Software Recommendations! We will need some more information to give good recommendations here. Please take a look at [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) Then please [edit] your question and see if you can incorporate some of these improvements. Examples of what's missing: what languages are acceptable, some "user story" (how it is supposed to be used, as this also helps to find the better candidates), what exactly it must/should support (functionality). Thanks for your patience in advance ;)

Comment: As windows does not allow more than one "virtual" mouse, any solution will involve some form of subterfuge - tricking the user into thinking there is more than one mouse.

Comment: Some additional details one would need to know before making a recommendation:  Given the trickery involved here, how much wool should be used to cover the users' eyes?  (e.g. do you need to see 4+ mouse cursors on screen, or is the single cursor provided by the OS good enough?)

Comment: Device simulation Framework from Microsoft I actually had working with vbscript but c++ or direct code support was poorly documented. It simulates multiple devices and sends input on its in-endpoint (input injection in ms device driver terms). It actually emulates and/or simulates devices but I have trouble with supporting it in direct managed languages (vb.net and c#).

Comment: This would be for the Kinect device. I need something that simulates multiple mouse devices because I need to simulate multiple players in a game. As stated above in more information, something for the Kinect similar to XPadder but supports multiple players.